# Dónde colocar las carpetas de recursos que trabajan con el archivo .WAR en Cpanel?

Tags: java, tomcat, cpanel

Buen día, estoy tratando de cargar una web creada con Java a Cpanel. Cargo el archivo ROOT.war y se carga en la carpeta jvm/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/domains/sendfac.com; pero no se en que carpeta cargar las carpetas de recursos que utiliza el archivo .War ... si cargo en el mismo lugar como lo hago en el localhost me sale el error "Estado HTTP 404 - El recurso requerido no está disponible.", puedo ver que hay varias carpetas adicionales en  jvm/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/domains/sendfac.com, pero no se si debo cargar en una de las otras y no me gustaría probar una por una por lo pesado del archivo. Gracias por sus aportes.

**Directorio Cpanel:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Error al cargar**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

La solución para estos casos en colocar todos los recursos que no son parte del archivo .war en un subdominio.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]